# Pass Vuex data to Firebase after Stripe payment

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, stripe-payments

It's my first time with firebase functions and stripe and I have a problem with adding document to firestore when payment goes success.
It's not predefined "product", more like custom article which is store in Vuex after creating process.
And here's my problem. I've got this function:

```
exports.stripeWebhook = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  const stripe = require("stripe")(functions.config().stripe.token);

  let event;
  try {
    const whSec = functions.config().stripe.payments_webhook_secret;

    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(
        req.rawBody,
        req.headers["stripe-signature"],
        whSec,
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("⚠️ Webhook signature verification failed.");
    return res.sendStatus(400);
  }

  const dataObject = event.data.object;

  await admin.firestore().collection("orders").doc().set({
    checkoutSessionId: dataObject.id,
    paymentStatus: dataObject.payment_status,
    amountTotal: dataObject.amount_total,
  });

  return res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

It's assing to checkout.session.completed event type in Stripe and send order details to firestore, but I don't know how to pass data from front there with onRequest function.
Also, because I'm using stripe chekout, I'm not sure how to keep data from vuex after payment. Store it in local storage on time of payment?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not use a stack snippet for code that isn't runnable. Stack snippets are only meant for HTML, CSS, and JavaScript code that can be run on a browser. Please format your code using a [code block](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/8289918) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can read data you have passed into the body of the request through the `req.body` object.

You would then have to save the information into a database location, Firestore or Realtime db that uses the stripe transaction ID as the document or node name.

This allows you to call another cloud function from the stripe on transaction update which can lookup the transaction ID to load the data for further processing.